# How to do nested sum in group by in optimized/one query in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

I've 3 tables, `Manager`, `Employee` & `Salary`. Following is the structure of all the tables.

**Manager**

```
id  | Name
---------
111 | AAA
222 | BBB
```

**Employee**

```
id  | Name | Manager_id | new_policy_deductions
----------------------------------
1   | A B  | 111        | 100
2   | A C  | 111        | 200
3   | C D  | 222        | 200
```

**Salary**

```
id  | employee_id | Month | Emp_Salary | Manager_id
---------------------------------------------------
1   | 1           | Jan   | 500        | 111
2   | 1           | Feb   | 500        | 111
3   | 1           | Mar   | 600        | 111
4   | 2           | Apr   | 500        | 111
5   | 1           | Apr   | 700        | 111
6   | 3           | Mar   | 300        | 222
7   | 3           | Apr   | 500        | 222
```

`employee_id` is foreign key from `Employee` table to `Salary` table & `manager_id` is foreign key from `Manager` table to other tables.

Now, I need to construct a query such that I get following result.

```
Manager_id | Net_Salary
-----------------------
111        | 2500
222        | 600
```

How did I reached that numbers?

Take sum of salaries of all the employees under one manager (500 + 500 + 600 + 500 + 700 = 2800) & then subtract all new_policy_deductions in that manager (100 + 200 = 300). It implies `111` will have 2500 (2800 - 300).
Similarly, for `222` we have 600.

I was able to achieve this using 2 queries, which are as follows,

```
x = select manager_id, sum(Emp_Salary) from Salary group by manager_id
y = select manager_id, sum(new_policy_deductions) from Employee group by manager_id

result = x - y
```

Can this be achieved in **single SQL query**? If yes, how?

**Note:**

- The actual table names are different then I used here.
- I can't modify table structure. It was designed long time ago.
- **Nested SQL query is not allowed**, as that is equivalent to 2 queries, and it will be inefficient.

**Edit:**

Following are the queries, which will help in creating dummy data.

```
create table manager (id int, name text);

create table employee (id int, name text, manager_id int, new_policy_deductions int);

create table salary(id int, employee_id int, emp_salary int, manager_id int);

select * from manager;
INSERT INTO manager
(`id`,
`name`)
VALUES
(111,'AAA'), (222,'BBB');

select * from employee;

INSERT INTO employee
(`id`,
`name`,
`manager_id`,
`new_policy_deductions`)
VALUES
(1,'A B',111,100), (2,'A C B',111,200), (3,'C A B',222,200);


select * from salary;
INSERT INTO salary
(`id`,
`employee_id`,
`month`,
`emp_salary`,
`manager_id`)
VALUES
(1,1,'Jan',500,111), (2,1,'Feb',500,111), (3,1,'Mar',600,111), (4,2,'Apr',500,111), (5,1,'Apr',700,111), (6,3,'Mar',300,222), (7,3,'Apr',500,222);
```

I've ignored foreign key constraints in query, as it is dummy data. Actual tables do have foreign key constraints.

Comment: Do you want to do this staff within a single query???

Comment: Yes, if it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.Manager_id, sumOfSalaries - sumOfDeductions 
FROM (
  SELECT Manager_id, SUM(Emp_Salary) AS sumOfSalaries
  FROM Salary 
  GROUP BY Manager_id) AS t1
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT Manager_id, SUM(new_policy_deductions) AS sumOfDeductions
  FROM Employee
  GROUP BY Manager_id
) AS t2 ON t1.Manager_id = t2.Manager_id
```

**Edit:**

```
SELECT t1.Id, t1.Name, 
       COALESCE(sumOfSalaries, 0) - COALESCE(sumOfDeductions, 0) AS Net_Salary
FROM Manager AS t1
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT Manager_id, SUM(Emp_Salary) AS sumOfSalaries
      FROM Salary 
      GROUP BY Manager_id
) AS t2 ON t1.Id = t2.Manager_id
  INNER JOIN (
      SELECT Manager_id, SUM(new_policy_deductions) AS sumOfDeductions
      FROM Employee
      GROUP BY Manager_id
) AS t3 ON t2.Manager_id = t3.Manager_id
```

Comment: I've another doubt, if `manager_id` is not present in `Salary` table, can similar thing be achieved? If yes, how?

Comment: @Abhishek If `manager_id` is not present is `Salary` table? Then he/she would have a *negative* salary? How is this even possible?

Comment: No. Salary can be joined using `employee` table. So, after that can it be done?

Comment: @Abhishek `Emp_Salary` is a field of `Salary` table. If there is no manager in this table at all, then how is the salary calculated in this case?

Comment: Something like this, Manager join with Employee on manager_id and Employee join with salary on employee_id.

Comment: I've just tested your query, it works. :) If you can share the answer for my second question, then it will be great!

Answer (score 1):

```
select e.manager_id, (sum(e.Emp_Salary)-sum(s.new_policy_deductions)) 
FROM Salary as s
LEFT JOIN Employee as e
ON s.manager_id=e.manager_id
group by e.manager_id
```

would something like this be what you are looking for? might need some editing (typos are possible I dont have you db to check across)

In question to the comment this might be something you are also interested in:

```
select e.manager_id, (sum(e.Emp_Salary)-sum(s.new_policy_deductions)) 
FROM Salary as s
LEFT JOIN Employee as e
ON e.id=s.employee_id
group by e.manager_id
```

This is the best I can think of at current with the tables shown

Comment: You are doing `group by s.manager_id` but not by `e.manager_id`, will it work correctly in grouping employee data?

Comment: @Abhishek that was a small mistake on my part, though it shouldnt matter... correcting.. it gets confusing when using simular names!

Comment: Let me give it a try and get back to you :)

Comment: I've another doubt, if `manager_id` is not present in `Salary` table, can similar thing be achieved? If yes, how?

Comment: I don't think a simple join yields correct results, since the grouping of values is incorrect.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos on the second maybe not, but the first statement should be ok? I dont have the ability to test it so I just wrote from the top of my head... otherwise I would have played with the solution and given a perfect one.

Comment: Have a look at how `Employee` records are joined: the same record will be included multiple times.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos then perhaps my second statement would be best suited for the original issue? from what i understand of these tables, though im unsure why they have employee ids and manager ids... maybe im missing a point

Comment: @silverpenguin we have manager ids and employees in separate table. It is for keep actual employee data separate from manager data.

Comment: @silverpenguin both queries are not yielding correct results. For convenience, I've added insert & create table queries in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I have a query that can help you: try this-

```
SELECT e.`Manager_id` as manager_id, (SELECT sum(s.`Emp_Salary`)
   FROM salary as s
   WHERE s.`Manager_id` = e.`Manager_id`) - sum(e.new_policy_deductions) as net_salary
FROM employee as e GROUP BY e.`Manager_id`
```

This is tested locally and output like you want. if some properties like-table name, field name change then please change. i think table names are are small later at my case.